# Einstein Content Selection - attribute mapping

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, content-builder

I want to use einstein content selection for a simple assortment banner at the end of a email.

I have 3 attributes in the asset and in the send-DE that have to match (must match is checked).

1. country --> country
2. assortment --> assortment
3. language --> language

When I am preview the block in a email (using the send DE with the matching attributes) I only get the fallback banner. Somebody with an idea?

Comment: Are you previewing with a subscriber that exists on All subscribers list? Assuming you have content that matches all three rules for the subscriber in question and its available

Comment: no. But I retried it with your idea and it is still not working.

Comment: Have you tried re-importing your DE recently in Einstein Content Selection?
I don't think the profile attributes are loaded into email preview unless the subscribers are on the All subscriber list.

Comment: I can confirm the profile rules don't work if the subscriber in question is not in All subs during preview and test. If you have added the subscriber to all subs and still see just the fall back image and you believe you have asset that should be server i would suggest opening a support case for assistance

Comment: thanks. I have tried your approaches but it is still not working. I´m gonna write a ticket

Comment: FYI: there was an update in Content Selection. Therefore I had to do the sync of the Send-DE again. Now it is working